# Как вы разбираетесь в исходниках новой для себя программы?

Tags: c++

К примеру есть [такая](https://code.google.com/p/brtghost/downloads/list) программа. Так вот, с чего бы вы начали? Просто открыли файл с main функцией и от него уже дальше пошли? Или может имеются какие-то другие методы?

Comment: Ну сначала я бы поинтересовался что это за программа и что она вообще делает\должна делать

Comment: @strol, Вы бы хоть [сюда](https://code.google.com/p/brtghost/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk) ссылку дали.

Там я попытался найти что-нибудь вроде README, но в итоге открыл changelog.txt

Comment: @avp, в той версии наверное нету, потому что не оригинал. Вот [оригинал][1], только без графической оболочки, хотя от оболочки все ровно исходников не было. И вот [readme][2] .   
У оригинала есть ещё официальный сайт [тут][3] и wiki [тут][4] .

  [1]: https://code.google.com/p/ghostplusplus/
  [2]: https://code.google.com/p/ghostplusplus/source/browse/trunk/readme.txt
  [3]: http://www.codelain.com/
  [4]: http://www.codelain.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: @strol,  спасибо, конечно, но я не собираюсь углубляться в этот проект.

Просто посмотрел минут пять и доложил о результатах.

--

Вообще обычно я ищу сначала какие-то текстовые описания структуры программы, но обычно их почти нет. 

Потом просматриваю названия файлов.

Потом смотрю на main. Очень часто это ничего не дает. 

Читаю .h файлы  и Makefile. Если программа хорошо спроектирована, то из описываемых там структур данных и констант появляется какое-то понимание внутренней структуры программы.

Дальше grep по структурам из .h и просмотр  фрагментов кода.

Разбираюсь в иерархии функций...

Comment: @avp, углубляться не нужно. С этим как-то сам постараюсь разобраться. Мне просто хотелось узнать примерную последовательность действий при разборе исходников, а тот проект дал, потому что слегка знаком с ним, на случай, если бы кто-то на его примере что-то объяснял. Но вы как раз описали то, что мне было нужно. Так что спасибо! Если у вас есть ещё какие-то действия между теми, что вы уже описали, то с удовольствием посмотрел бы).

Comment: @strol в своё время по этой теме меня поразила книга Лингер Р., Миллс Х., Уитт Б. Теория и практика структурного программирования (напр: http://www.twirpx.com/file/940600/ ). Правда это было ещё до исторического материализма, пардон, до засилья ООП.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хороший вопрос на самом-то деле, попытаюсь дать хотя бы если не развернутый, то хотя бы дельный совет.

1. Попытайтесь понять что делает данная программа, для чего она вообще предназначена.
2. Загрузите проект в какую-нибудь из широко известных IDE - подойдет Eclipse, CodeBlocks, Visual Studio, QT Creator. Все эти IDE индексируют типы и их объявления, что позволяет их потом искать а также находить ссылки на них в программе - search for references, иногда очень помогает.
3. Можете запустить проект в дебаг режиме, и поставить точку останова в интересующем вас месте. Начать дебажить можно с главной функции - main'а.
4. Если что-то сильно не понятно, можно попытаться пообщаться с разработчиком программы. Обычно это помогает.
5. Поизучайте типы, структуры, классы, функции, методы, и прочие объявления программы. Как правило если Вы знаете, что Вы ищете (например, алгоритм обработки пакетов, приходящих от клиента к серверу), то процесс поиска искомого места в программе не должен занять много времени.
6. Никто не может запретить Вам дебажить отдельные функции, и скармливать им какие-то свои данные (при необходимости).

   Одним словом используйте все доступные Вам средства, и успех не заставит себя долго ждать + не забывайте заглядывать в документацию и гугл.

Answer (score 4):

Я пытаюсь что-то добавить и/или поменять. Ну то есть условно кнопочка или параметр командной строки. Во время отладки выставлять брейкпоинты в определённых местах и смотреть call stack.

Да, важное забыл сказать. Под MSVS есть очень полезный плагин, называется [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/). Вообще он платный, но он стоит своих денег (есть триальный период). Улучшает подсвечивание, автокомплит человеческий, но самое главное в контексте данного вопроса - это поиск и переход по упоминанием символов. Анализатор кода намного круче встроенного, очень удобно. Плюс появляется кнопочка Go которая в любой момент перебрасывает между определением/объявлением чего бы то ни было (что сейчас под курсором). Анализировать код становится намного проще.

Для других платформ (для всех на самом деле, IDE-независимая штука) я могу порекомендовать [Klokwork](http://www.klocwork.com/). Оно правда для одного будет слишком, скорее для команды разработчиков, но проще решений я не знаю. Там и анализ структуры, и поиск ошибок (что-то вроде lint, но интересней) и всё что угодно. Тоже вроде не бесплатный, зато невероятно мощный и вроде есть триальный период.

В принципе, [есть аналоги](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis), но я с ними не работал, так что мне рекомендовать сложно.

Answer (score 3):

Можно скормить программу в Umbrello (входит в КДЕ) или в [Медузу](http://medoosa.sourceforge.net/)
и посмотреть аннотированные исходники и диаграмму классов.

Comment: Попробовал Umbrello, но диаграмма же автоматически не строится. Хотя странно, там же почти все для этого есть, как мне показалось. Или я что-то не так делал. А если все же нельзя, то есть ли аналоги, которые бы смогли построить диаграмму автоматически?